# python3 binary with SUID cannot execute command as `root`

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, suid

As the title suggests, my `/usr/bin/python3.10` binary cannot be executed under root privilege even though I set the right to `-rwsr-xr-x`.

I tested using command `/usr/bin/python3.10 -c "import os; os.system('whoami')"`. The result is not `root` as expected, rather it is the username of the user executed such command.

However when I do a `ps auxf` command, I could see that the username of the above python process (the value at the first column) is still `root`.

I am testing on Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: This seems like a **extremely bad idea**. If you make python a setuid binary it means anyone can run any python script as root. Even making a individual script setuid is *a very bad idea* since you can manipulate the python import tree to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Thank you I know what I'm doing I'm just testing linux features. I'm testing on my local VM so it's safe.